# Why does a reduced compound become a better electron donor?

Tags: redox

When a compound gains an electron, why are they more likely to give them up (i.e. become stronger reducing agents)?

Answer (score 2):

Simple electrostatic repulsion can be used to explain this. For example, if you have $\ce{O^2-}$, there are 8 protons in the nucleus, but 10 electrons, so there is a net negative charge of 2. Like charges repel, pushing the electrons away.

BTW, *compounds* rarely "gain an electron", the reactive species are usually *[radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_%28chemistry%29)*.